# BroadcastReceiver doens't work between two Services

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

My broadcast receiver doens't work between two Services..

here are codes

[First Sevice]

```
class ServiceHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

       case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
            Log.d("MainService_Handler", "Service - MESSAGE_READ: ");

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            READ_DATA = readBuf;
            String strBuf = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            READ_STRING = strBuf;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainService.this, InputHelperService.class);
            intent.setAction(InputHelperService.READ_MESSAGE);
            intent.putExtra("read", readBuf[1]);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            //inputCommitment(readBuf[0]);

            break;
```

[Second Service]

public class InputHelperService extends InputMethodService {

```
public static String READ_MESSAGE = "com.example.eyelink.READMESSAGE";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.i("InputHelperService", "InputHelperService - onStartCommand()");

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("READ_MESSAGE");
    registerReceiver(messageReceiver, intentFilter);
    Log.i("InputHelperService", "InputHelperService - onStartCommand(): register the receiver");

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Log.i("InputHelperService", "InputHelperService: onDestroy()");
    unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
}

...



public final BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.i("InputHelperService", "InputHelperService: Broadcast onReceive()");
        if(intent.getAction().equals(READ_MESSAGE)){
            byte data = intent.getExtras().getByte("read");
            Log.i("InputHelperService", "InputHelperService: Broadcast onReceive() - " + data);
        }
    }
};
```

}

but there are no responses from my Broadcast receiver.

what is wrong?

Comment: *Service Handler class of first service is an inner class.

Comment: are you sure `InputHelperService` service is running when `sendBroadcast(intent);` method called ?

Comment: yes it is running well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

> intentFilter.addAction("READ_MESSAGE");

You are using different `Action` for preparing `intentFilter` to register receiver and for sending broadcast. use same action string as:

```
intentFilter.addAction(InputHelperService.READ_MESSAGE);
```

And send broadcast as:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(InputHelperService.READ_MESSAGE); 
    intent.putExtra("read", readBuf[1]);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thx. but it returns the same result

Comment: @류근웅 using different actions is not critical?? You are not registering broadcast in manifest so it's critical.

Comment: use localbroadcasts instead.

Comment: I modified code according to your help but it returns same result.

Comment: @류근웅: you also need  to change `sendBroadcast`  intent see my answer